# How to debug Excel Add - ins custom functions code in JS?

Tags: excel, debugging, excel-formula, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

Hello Everyone one I am new to excel add ins custom functions , I have written functions on functions.js files and also added in manifest file and when I run NPM run start its work perfectly in excel , but when I add console.log() in that function , I am unable to view or debug that value ?

Comment: Please see if this article helps: [UI-less custom functions debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-debugging).

Comment: I have already go through the article , but nothing work ,

Comment: You need to give more detail than just "nothing work". At what point in the article does something go wrong? What goes wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RickKirkham when I start Debugging in Visual studio code its showing logs for taskPane .js files , does not show any logs for custom functions files .

Comment: Where are you seeing these logs? Could you add a screenshot to your original question?